# iOS7 AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction causes video frame to freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I'm working with modifying some video via `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` in the iOS7 SDK.

The following code used to work on iOS 6.1.3, but in iOS7 the video is frozen on the first frame (though I can still hear the audio ok).  I got rid of all actual transformations I was applying to verify that adding a video composition alone causes problems.

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:inputFileURL options:NULL];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction =
[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoAssetTrack];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);
mainComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainComposition.frameDuration = videoAsset.duration;
mainComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);

...
exportSession.videoComposition = mainComposition;
```

If I do not set the `videoComposition` attribute of `exportSession` then the video records ok, but I cannot apply any transformations. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Same here, no help on the internet

Answer (score 1):

A good way to debug issues with the video composition is to use `[AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset]`. The returned `AVMutableVideoComposition` should work correctly. Then you can compare the contents of the `instructions` array with your instructions.

To increase the confusion levels, the `asset` there can also be an `AVComposition`. I think the `AVFoundation` team didn't do the best job when naming these things....

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling as well with AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction and mix video with CALayers. After a few days trying different ways what I realise is that the time of the assets are pretty important.
The proper way to find out the time of each asset is use the property:

> loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"]

```
    //Asset url
    NSURL *assetUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_firstVideoFilePath];

   //audio/video assets
   AVURLAsset * videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:assetUrl options:nil];

   //var to store the duration
   CMTime __block durationTime;

   //And here we'll be able to proper get the asset duration
   [videoAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"] completionHandler: ^{
         Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([videoAsset duration]);
         durationTime = [videoAsset duration];
         //At this point you have the proper asset duration value, you can start any video processing from here. 
  }];
```

Hope this helps to anyone with the same issue.